# Mean of each column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Working with a dataframe that contain an specific binary column (all in numpy array), in example:

```
[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

That's possible to apply a loop for iterate all columns inside that column?

i.e

In my case i need to get the mean of values in each column, like:

```
# Mean of position [0]           # Mean of position[3]
    1.                               1.
    1.                               0.
    1.                               0.
    0.                               1.
    1.                               1.
    0.                               1.
    1.                               0.
    1.                               1.
    1.                               1.
    0.                               0.
```

There is any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: what about `df.mean()`?

Comment: Perhaps something with df.apply(np.mean)?

Comment: "That's possible to apply a loop for iterate all columns inside that column?" This is confusing, could you rephrase please ?

Comment: From your examples, it seems that you're taking a slice of the array. Are you sure that you are looking for the mean?

Comment: @Chris Yes, sure. Need to do some slice and calculate the mean of values inside each sliced column. But i don't know how to implement that in some loop for iterate all the values...

Comment: Check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html with axis=1

Answer (score 2):

Just use `iloc` with `mean`:

```
meanZero = df.iloc[0].mean()
meanThird= df.iloc[3].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mean function from numpy.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

So in your case, I think you are looking for `np.mean(a, axis=1)`